# node-webkit MySQL connection Error - ER_HANDSHAKE_ERROR: Bad handshake

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-webkit, node-mysql

I am using Node-Webkit for creating desktop application using NodeJS.

In this i need to get data from MySQL database. For this am using node-mysql module and the following code is used to connect MySQL server using node-mysql.

```
var mysql_con = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql_con.createConnection({
      host     : input.host,
      user     : input.username,
      password : input.password,
      database : input.database
    });
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error : '+err.stack);
        }
        console.log('Success');
    });
```

if i run in the command line of my Windows machine, connection has been established and **Success** has been printed in console. But if i pack and run the code in the node-webkit's nw.exe its giving the following error in web console

```
Error : Error: ER_HANDSHAKE_ERROR: Bad handshake
at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\DOCUME~1\admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\nw4480_11607\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:48:14)
at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\DOCUME~1\admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\nw4480_11607\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:101:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\DOCUME~1\admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\nw4480_11607\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:270:23)
at Parser.write (C:\DOCUME~1\admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\nw4480_11607\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:77:12)
at Protocol.write (C:\DOCUME~1\admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\nw4480_11607\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\DOCUME~1\admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\nw4480_11607\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:82:28)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:104:17)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:156:16)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:123:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:520:20)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (C:\DOCUME~1\admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\nw4480_11607\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:135:48)
at Protocol.handshake (C:\DOCUME~1\admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\nw4480_11607\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:41)
at Connection.connect (C:\DOCUME~1\admin\LOCALS~1\Temp\nw4480_11607\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:108:18)
at Object.mysql.testConnection
```

Kindly suggest me solution to establish the MySQL connection through node-webkit.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem... and downgrading node webkit to the version 0.8.6 did the trick...

i hope this help you...

Comment: What's the mysql version in the package.json or package-lock.json?